# How to convert an array of maps to a list?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

SelectableImageModel:

```
public class SelectableImageModel {

    @PropertyName("FILE_NAME")
    public String fileName;
    @PropertyName("DURATION")
    public int duration;
    @PropertyName("EXPIRATION_DATE")
    public String expirationDate;

    @PropertyName("FILE_NAME")
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    @PropertyName("FILE_NAME")
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @PropertyName("DURATION")
    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    @PropertyName("DURATION")
    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @PropertyName("EXPIRATION_DATE")
    public String getExpirationDate() {
        return expirationDate;
    }

    @PropertyName("EXPIRATION_DATE")
    public void setExpirationDate(String expirationDate) {
        this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
    }

}
```

**Code**

```
if (documentSnapshot.get("IMAGES") != null) {
    List<SelectableImageModel> imagesList = (List<SelectableImageModel>) documentSnapshot.get("IMAGES");
    Log.w("ABC", "... " + documentSnapshot.get("IMAGES"));
    Log.w("ABC", "... " + documentSnapshot.get("IMAGES").getClass());
    Log.w("ABC", "... " + documentSnapshot.get("IMAGES").getClass().getName());
    Log.w("ABC", imagesList == null ? "null" : "notnull");
    Log.w("ABC", ". " + imagesList.size()); //Output is 3
    Log.w("ABC", ". " + imagesList.get(0));
    try {
        Log.w("ABC", imagesList.get(0).getFileName().getClass().getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("ABC", "... " + e); // Always print this exception -> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.xxx.adminpanel.app.models.SelectableImageModel
    }
}
```

[image]

The `IMAGES` field is an array where each item inside it is a map. As you can see in the code above, I'm attempting to convert this array to a list. However, I'm encountering an exception. What am I missing?

Comment: This is failing: `(List<SelectableImageModel>) documentSnapshot.get("IMAGES");` You can't cast document data directly to a custom java class.  You have to manually populate the class by pulling each field out of the document snapshot and putting it into the class.  Document fields are only ever going to be String, Long, Double, Timestamp, Boolean, DocumentReference, Map<Object>, List<Object>.

Comment: @DougStevenson I hope you can provide a solution in the form of code to precisely demonstrate what you mean.

Comment: I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) on how to deal with data coming from document snapshots. It's pretty straightforward.  I also recommend updating your question to be more clear about where you are stuck with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DocumentSnapshot#get(String field)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#get(java.lang.String)) method, returns an object of type [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). So the following line of code will definitely fail:

```
(List<SelectableImageModel>) documentSnapshot.get("IMAGES");
```

Because in Java, there is no way you can perform such a cast. If you however try to perform such a cast, you'll most likely get a [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html). To get the `IMAGES` array as a `List<SelectableImageModel>`, I recommend you create another class that looks like this:

```
public class Document {
    public List<SelectableImageModel> imagesList;
}
```

And to read the document, you have to use [DocumentSnapshot#toObject(Class valueType)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#toObject(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) method instead. So in code, it should look like this:

```
List<SelectableImageModel> imagesList = documentSnapshot.toObject(Document.class).imagesList;
```

So first you have to convert the `DocumentSnapshot` object into an object of type `Document`, and then read the public `imagesList` field from within the object. For more information, I also recommend you read this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10).